# Change Django Form Attribute on view

Tags: django, forms, view, django-forms, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using a Django Form with a `DatePicker` widget. I have to define the Min and Max date of the `DatePicker` on a class level. I would like to have these two values change when I run my view, otherwise, it keeps the Min and Max date values from the time that I start my Django server.

```
from django import forms
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

MIN_DATE = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
MAX_DATE = (dt.datetime.today() + dt.timedelta(days=92)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')


class TableEdit(forms.Form):
    Account = forms.CharField(label='Account', max_length=10)
    Hedge = forms.CharField(label='Hedge', max_length=10)
    Date = forms.DateField(widget=DatePickerInput(
        options={
            'format': 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            'minDate': MIN_DATE,
            'maxDate': MAX_DATE
        }))
```

How can I modify my `MIN_DATE` and `MAX_DATE` form attributes every time that I call my form from a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in the form's `__init__` method, like so:

```
class TableEdit(forms.Form):
    Account = forms.CharField(label='Account', max_length=10)
    Hedge = forms.CharField(label='Hedge', max_length=10)
    Date = forms.DateField()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TableEdit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    min_date = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    max_date = (dt.datetime.today() + dt.timedelta(days=92)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    self.fields['Date'].widget = DatePickerInput(
        options={
            'format': 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            'minDate': min_date,
            'maxDate': max_date
        })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I tried a similar syntax for an hour but I couldn't gather my head around it. Your answer helped me clarify and learn about how classes work!